# Request post with AngularJS (and app)

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

In my JS I have:

```
var request = $http({
  method: "post", //or "get"
  url: $scope.ownServer+"get.php?num=1234",
  data: {num: '1234'}
});
```

In my server I have:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *"); //or GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

**First problem:**
If I use "get" method, I need to write data in the url, like "?num=1234", but it works.
If I use "post" method, it doesn't work. I've also tried with "Access-Control-Allow-Method: GET, POST, PUT" but nothing.. The error in console is "XMLHttpRequest cannot load"

**Second problem:**
How can allow access only to my app (made with Cordova and AngularJS)?

Comment: What do you use for your backend?

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps the HTTP method is case-sensitive?, i.e. maybe you should use `method: 'POST'`

Comment: @yarons is correct. Refer to the official [$http examples](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), they are using capital 'POST'. Btw, you can also use `$http.post()` or `$http.get()'` to avoid this issue altogether.

Comment: @ShivasJayaram for the server, I use altervista, at the moment.

Comment: @yarons yes, I thought so too, but I think I've tried "post" and "POST"..

Comment: @simone_s1994 did you try to use `$http.post()` instead?

Comment: @yarons no... Tomorrow I will try it, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @yarons yes, it works! Now I have to solve only the second problem.

Comment: can you explain better the second problem?

Comment: @yarons I would like to "protect" my server. From my app (cordova+angularjs) I make Ajax request, but how can I allow access to the server only from my app?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I'll try to answer both your questions:

1. Use `$http.post` instead of `$http` because that seem to have solved your problem.
2. I would suggest something like JWT (JSON Web Token), where your app creates the token with some secret key and adds that token to request headers, and your server decrypts that token to verify it's from your app.